# How to mirror a composition?

Tags: after-effects

I have a moving solid mask composition, which forms a white line that moves vertically from the middle to the left and back.

I now want to create a copy of that composition, mirror it and link the position. So that the mirrored comp will move from middle to right and back.

How could I achieve this? Setting the `width = -100%` did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pre comp your layer, then apply the Mirror effect to the comp.  If your comps are 1920x1080, set the mirror centre to 960x540, and the reflection angle to 0.[image]

I think your scaling to -100% didn't work because it's a masked layer.  You might have more luck using a shape layer to create your line, then you should be able to scale it as you suggested.

Comment: Masks transform with their layers, so that's not the reason it didn't work.

Comment: See my comment above on your answer - the mirror is needed to maintain mirrored movement - I should have made it clearer in my answer

Comment: This did not mirror the movement.

Answer (score 1):

Did you unlink the scale x and y before you set it? if you don't the **y** will be set to **-100** too. It's the little chain link next to the value.

[image: linked and unlinked scale]

What you described should work, masks are transformed with their layers.
[image: mirrored layer]

There's a more convenient way of flipping a layer - by going to the **Layer** menu and choosing `Layer>Transform>Flip Horizontal`

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of the movement - the original question says the line moves up and to the left, so the mirrored object should move up and right.  If you mirror using horizontal scale of -100%, any movement keyframes will still move up and left.  Same if you used Transform -> Flip Horizontal.  The quickest/simplest way to get mirrored movement was by pre-comping and using a Mirror effect.

Comment: I was assuming that the OP had already precomped - since he said: "I now want to create a copy of that composition".